# ffmpeg library convert the layout in LTR direction

Tags: android, android-resources, android-ffmpeg

I have used FFMpeg for video trim. loadBinary method of FFMpeg distorts the layout to LTR direction.I have instantiated its instance in a thread and also set the locale forcefully in Finish method of loadBinary method but that doesn't solves the issue. I am currently instantiating it at Application level. I am using the library 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'. Below is my code of instantiation

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
            try {
                ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure() {}

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
                        Resources resources =context.getResources();
                        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
                        config.locale = locale;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                            config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
                        }
                        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
                    }
                });
            } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {

            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: use this library  `implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'`

Comment: Also used this one but the issue persist

Comment: were you able to sort out this issue using above library?

Comment: I didn't had that issue with ffmpeg libraries

Comment: So did you used the ffmpeg library simply instantiating and calling loadBinary causes the above issue.

Comment: I used the library that I told and it has execute method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194088/discussion-between-anuj-kalal-and-vivek-mishra).

Comment: Thank you, we got the solution using the above library

Comment: @AnujKalal what exactly worked for you? I'm facing the same issue.